# iterar lista creada con dump

Tags: python

tengo esta lista en un archivo y necesito iterar sobre ella pero no se como hacerlo.

mi lista tiene este formato lo arroja dump:

```
[["PROVIDER NOMBRE", "NOMBRE CANAL", "http://source"], ["PROVIDER NOMBRE", "OTRO NOMBRE CANAL", "http://source"], ["PROVIDER OTRO NOMBRE", "OTRO NOMBRE CANAL", "http://source"], etc....]]
```

los elementos PROVIDER NOMBRE Y PROVIDER OTRO NOMBRE etc..abarcan varios elementos con distintos http source y NOMBRE CANAL OTRO NOMBRE CANAL etc....

Necesito escribir este contenido:
donde #NAME, #SERVICE 1:0:1:1:1:0:0:0:0:0: y #DESCRIPTION se añadirian al contenido iterado de la lista quedaría o pretendo que quede tal que así:

un archivo con este contenido donde debe recoger todas las conincidencias de PROVIDER NOMBRE

```
#NAME PROVIDER NOMBRE
#SERVICE 1:0:1:1:1:0:0:0:0:0:http://source:NOMBRE CANAL
#DESCRIPTION NOMBRE CANAL
```

otro archivo con este contenido donde debe recoger todas las conincidencias de PROVIDER OTRO NOMBRE:

```
#NAME PROVIDER OTRO NOMBRE
#SERVICE 1:0:1:1:1:0:0:0:0:0:http://source:OTRO NOMBRE CANAL
#DESCRIPTION OTRO NOMBRE CANAL
```

me gustaria crear un archivo por cada PROVIDER NOMBRE y escribir en ellos los datos de arriba que correspondan a cada PROVIDER NOMBRE donde este elemento como digo abarca varios elementos http source y NOMBRE DE CANAL.

pienso que los bucles pueden actuar pero no se me ocurre que estrategia seguir para conseguir el resultado que pretendo.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos. Lectura recomendada: ¿Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1):

este es mi código donde escribo con el método dump mi lista de PROVEEDORES en mi archivo mifile.json.

```
with open(/etc/mifile.json, "w") as f:
    dump(list, f, indent=4)
```

de esta manera obtengo en mi archivo json lo que necesito y hasta aquí todo bien:

```
[
    "PROVIDERNAME",
    "PROVIDERNAME2",
    "ULTIMOPROVIDER"
]
```

aqui me viene mi problema, este archivo necesito que tenga esta sintaxis, obtener un diccionario donde todos los elementos del diccionario en CATEGORIES apunte cada PROVIDER A SU PROPIO PROVIDER, es decir necesito que este archivo tenga esta sintaxis donde el encabezado debe tener los tres primeros elementos siempre fijos + CATEGORIES que es desde donde hago la llamada desde keys:

```
{
    "PORT": 80,
    "USER": "",
    "PASSWORD": "",
    "CATEGORIES": {
      "PROVIDERNAME": ["PROVIDERNAME"],
      "PROVIDERNAME2": ["PROVIDERNAME2"],
      "ULTIMOPROVIDER": ["ULTIMOPROVIDER"]
  }
}
```